Angular MatTree with FlatTreeControl and CdkVirtualScrollViewport, preserve expanded node
I want store the opening state of the nodes so that in virtual scrolling the user finds them already open if he had them open:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cqbnsy
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection,
} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { CdkVirtualScrollViewport } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { FlatTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {
  MatTreeFlatDataSource,
  MatTreeFlattener,
} from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';

export interface NestedFileSystemItem {
  children: NestedFileSystemItem[];
  name: string;
}

export interface NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode {
  expandable: boolean;
  name: string;
  level: number;
}

const DATI = new Array(100_000)
  .fill({
    name: 'Folder',
    children: [
      { name: 'File 1' },
      { name: 'File 2' },
      {
        name: 'Sub Folder',
        children: [
          { name: 'Sub File 1' },
          { name: 'Sub File 2' },
          {
            name: 'Sub Sub Folder',
            children: [{ name: 'Sub Sub File 1' }, { name: 'Sub Sub File 2' }],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  })
  .map((item, index) => {
    return { ...item, name: item.name + ' (' + index + ')' };
  });

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatIconModule, MatButtonModule, MatTreeModule, ScrollingModule],
  styles: `@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";`,
  template: `
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="48" style="height: 500px;">
    <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let item of fullDataSource"></ng-container>

    <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding>
          <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
          {{node.name}}
        </mat-tree-node>

        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
          <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                  [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
              {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
          </button>
          {{node.name}}
        </mat-tree-node>
    </mat-tree>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode>;
  treeFlattener: MatTreeFlattener<
    NestedFileSystemItem,
    NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode
  >;
  dataSource: MatTreeFlatDataSource<
    NestedFileSystemItem,
    NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode
  >;
  fullDataSource = DATI;
  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) virtualScroll!: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  constructor() {
    this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
      this.transformer,
      this._getLevel,
      this._isExpandable,
      this._getChildren
    );
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode>(
      this._getLevel,
      this._isExpandable
    );
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(
      this.treeControl,
      this.treeFlattener
    );
    this.dataSource.data = this.fullDataSource.slice(0, 10);
  }

  transformer = (
    node: NestedFileSystemItem,
    level: number
  ): NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode => ({
    expandable: !!node.children,
    name: node.name,
    level,
  });

  _getLevel = (node: NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode) => node.level;

  _isExpandable = (node: NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode) => node.expandable;

  _getChildren = (
    node: NestedFileSystemItem
  ): Observable<NestedFileSystemItem[]> => of(node.children);

  hasChild = (_: number, _nodeData: NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode) =>
    _nodeData.expandable;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.virtualScroll.renderedRangeStream.subscribe((range: any) => {
      this.dataSource.data = this.fullDataSource.slice(range.start, range.end);
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection(),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));


Unfortunately I am unable to make it work with flat datasource but it is achievable using nested data source, please find below working stackblitz and a reference stackblitz used for solving this problem. This nested tree data has the advantage of controlling the child rendering container, which we can hide using the css [class.example-tree-invisible]="node.expanded" and by using the property expanded which we store on the data object, we can make the view remember which was opened.
FULL CODE:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection,
} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { CdkVirtualScrollViewport } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { FlatTreeControl, NestedTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {
  MatTreeFlatDataSource,
  MatTreeFlattener,
  MatTreeNestedDataSource,
} from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

export interface NestedFileSystemItem {
  children: NestedFileSystemItem[];
  name: string;
}

export interface NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode {
  expandable: boolean;
  name: string;
  level: number;
}

const DATI = new Array(100_000)
  .fill({
    name: 'Folder',
    children: [
      { name: 'File 1' },
      { name: 'File 2' },
      {
        name: 'Sub Folder',
        children: [
          { name: 'Sub File 1' },
          { name: 'Sub File 2' },
          {
            name: 'Sub Sub Folder',
            children: [{ name: 'Sub Sub File 1' }, { name: 'Sub Sub File 2' }],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  })
  .map((item, index) => {
    return { ...item, name: item.name + ' (' + index + ')' };
  });

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  styles: `@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";`,
  template: `
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="48" style="height: 500px;">
    <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let item of fullDataSource"></ng-container>

    <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
    <li class="mat-tree-node">
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
      {{node.name}}
    </li>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNestedChild">
    <li>
      <div class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button
                [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name"
                (click)="changeState(node)">
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{node.expanded ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        {{node.name}}
      </div>
      <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="node.expanded">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode>;
  treeFlattener: any;
  dataSource: any;
  fullDataSource = DATI;
  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) virtualScroll!: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  constructor() {
    this.treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<any>(this._getChildren);
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource();
    this.dataSource.data = this.fullDataSource.slice(0, 10);
  }

  transformer = (
    node: NestedFileSystemItem,
    level: number
  ): NestedFileSystemItemFlatNode => ({
    expandable: !!node.children,
    name: node.name,
    level,
  });

  private _getChildren = (node: any) => node?.children;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.virtualScroll.renderedRangeStream.subscribe((range: any) => {
      this.dataSource.data = this.fullDataSource.slice(range.start, range.end);
    });
  }

  hasNestedChild = (_: number, nodeData: any) => nodeData?.children?.length > 0;

  changeState(node: any) {
    node.expanded = !node.expanded;
    console.log(node);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection(),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));

Stackblitz Demo
Reference Stackblitz Demo

Perfect! thanks!!!
